# Controls not allowing to enter new data after databinding statically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using **BindingNavigator** control in my windows form, and I've bound a data to textboxes and combo boxes on my form to navigate through records statically, and on  clicking "Add new Item" button on my form, I'm emptying all the data of my form like:

> textbox1.Text = "";  combobox1.Text =
>   "";

and then trying to enter new data, but all the input boxes of my form not allowing me to enter any data, and also all the buttons of this form only have stopped functioning. May I know the reason and how can I sort out this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using a BindingNavigator setting the Text properties of the controls will (should) update the item bound to them.

Instead, add a new item to the collection that you are using as a BindingSource and navigate to it via the navigator. For instance, you might do something like this:

```
myBindingNavigator.BindingSource.AddNew();
myBindingNavigator.BindingSource.MoveLast();
```

That should add a new element to the binding source, and move to it so that it is immediately editable via the UI.